# Java Collections.sort function converts to Kotlin throws error

Tags: kotlin

I'm a newer to kotlin, now I have a java code like this:

```
    Collections.sort(mHullList, new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(MatOfPoint lhs, MatOfPoint rhs) {
            return Double.compare(Imgproc.contourArea(rhs),Imgproc.contourArea(lhs));
        }
    });
```

when I convert it to kotlin with IDE, like this:

```
    Collections.sort(mHullList, object : Comparator<MatOfPoint?> {
        fun compare(lhs: MatOfPoint, rhs: MatOfPoint): Int {
            return java.lang.Double.compare(
                Imgproc.contourArea(rhs),
                Imgproc.contourArea(lhs)
            )
        }
    })
```

It throws the error in object : Comparator<MatOfPoint?>:

Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member.

how to resolve this, thanks.

```
val mHullList: MutableList<MatOfPoint> = ArrayList()
```

Comment: You are creating a `Comparator<MatOfPoint?>`, so `compare` should take `MatOfPoint?`, not `MatOfPoint`. If the collection doesn't contain nulls, making a `Comparator<MatOfPoint>` would also work. Also, you don't need an `object` here - just use `compareBy`.

Comment: That said, can `mHullList` contain nulls? Does `Imgproc.contourArea` throw an exception when null is passed to it? Or does it handle nulls gracefully?

Comment: I've edited your code to format your last line properly: previously, it wasn't showing that `mHullList` was a `MutableList<MatOfPoint>`. Since it only holds non-null instances, you should make the comparator take non-null generic parameter, and declare `compare` as `override`. Also, don't just do an automatic conversion to Kotlin using the IDE. You really need to understand Kotlin and manually check conversions every time, because it doesn't always get them right. Treat them as a guide.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks, mHullList doesn't  contain nulls. I have changed Comparator<MatOfPoint?> to Comparator<MatOfPoint>,it still throws other errors, can I just use mHullList.sortBy { Imgproc.contourArea(it) } to implement Collections.sort?

Comment: @k314159 thanks for your advice, you are right, I need to understand the code. My team use Kotlin as our coding language, i'm a beginer, i'm a frontend engineer so I really don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin is a language oriented to many things seen as an improvement of Java. One of them is the concept of `null-safety`. A good practice in `Kotlin` is to make code that is guaranteed to never generate null values. This is by default. When you do `MatOfPoint?` in the code, you are allowing values to be null in your comparator. The compiler sees `nullables` as different types as `non-nullables`. What the `IDE` is telling you is that you have not implemented the comparator with the nullables. So your comparator is not a comparator of `MatOfPoint`. It is a comparator of `MatOfPoint?` and you have implemented the function to comparae `non-nullables`. If you are coming from any language where the objects are all `nullable` by default, then this may sound strange in the beginning but you get used to. Maybe the `IDE` should be clearer on what it is trying to tell you. This `Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member.` is in my view not a very clear error message from the `IDE`. In any case, removing the `?` from your code is not the only thing to do to fix your code. You'll also need an `override` before `fun`. I picked up your example and simplified it as much as I could and this could be a better option:

```
sort(mHullList) { lhs, rhs ->
    Imgproc.contourArea(lhs).compareTo(Imgproc.contourArea(rhs))
}
```

As a follow-up to a comment by @LouisWasserman, let me put here an example on how to do this in an immutable way:

```
 val newList = mHullList.sortedBy {  Imgproc.contourArea(it) }
```

In this last suggestion, the code is using pure immutability in `Kotlin` which is best practice, but you'll get a new sorted list and so you need to adapt your code to work considering immutability and no longer considering unexpected mutations.

If you are curious, `sortBy` would also work, but the list would have to be converted to a mutable list and the example would look like this:

```
val newList = mHullList.toMutableList()
newList.sortBy { Imgproc.contourArea(it) }
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, you might as well use `sortBy(mHullList) { Imgproc.contourArea(it) }`.

Comment: Yes! that is indeed even better @LouisWasserman. I'm going to update my answer. Thanks for your input

Comment: Oh @LouisWasserman, `sortBy` is only for immutable lists which are immutable and that goes against some of the `Kolin` tenants. I will add `sortedBy` though as a follow up to your comment.

Comment: the original post uses `Collections.sort`, which is also for mutable lists.  Your original answer also uses `sort`, which is only for mutable lists.

Comment: Sorry, I made a few typos in my answer to you @LouisWasserman.  It's late I'm sorry :) What I mean to say is that `sortBy` is not available for immutable lists. And so the only way to use it is to convert the list to a mutable list first.

Comment: I think `Collections.sort` bypasses all of this because it just works. I'm actually running all of these examples as we speak, so I can confirm everything that I am saying in realtime @LouisWasserman

Comment: `Collections.sort` and `sort` should do exactly the same thing in the same circumstances, to the same values.  It does nothing magical that `sort` doesn't.

Comment: In particular, `Collections.sort` _compiles_ for unmodifiable lists, and probably even works on `listOf` etc., but only because those collections aren't actually immutable, they just pretend to be.  `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` is equivalent to `(list as MutableList<T>).sort(comparator)`.

Comment: Are you talking about `sort` or `sortBy` @LouisWasserman? Because now I'm confused. Your first comment mentions using the `sortBy`. And on this last comment we both agree. I know that and this is because those `sort`s are coming from the `JDK` and not from the `Kotlin standard library` and the JDK knows nothing about the `Kotlin` immutable types. It just knows about its own immutable types.

Comment: `sort` and `sortBy` are essentially the same here, `sortBy` just uses a custom comparator based on the argument.

Comment: @LouisWasserman they do perform similar operations but they are not strictly the same and the distinction is very important and actually very interesting because it showcases interop problems between Kotlin and Java. But most importantly here is that we understand that `sortBy` does not exist in `Collections` as mentioned in the Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html.